# Visual Studio C++ Project for Linux, how to run .out file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, linux-mint

Im using Visual Studio 2022 and have created a C++ project for linux.

I followed this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/connect-to-your-remote-linux-computer?view=msvc-170

And got a running OpenGL-application in Linux via Remote Debugging in Visual Studio.

[image]

I see a .out-file in Linux but I can not run it.

[image]

So, how do I compile an executable file, so I can run it on Linux Mint? I am using Linux Mint.

Comment: "can not run it", as in, when you double-click it, it doesn't start? Probably the "executable" flag is not set on it?  (`chmod +x yourfile.out` would fix that). It seems you generated the file not on the system that you want to run it on - note that generating a portable Linux binary (i.e. one which runs on multiple different Linux distributions/versions thereof) is not a trivial task (as in, not recommended, you should build specifically for the distribution you intend to run it unless you go for platforms such as flatpak or snap)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using linux, you can use `cpp` or `g++` for compiling your code. Linux usually have the g++. Run it by `g++ filename.cpp` and you will get a ELF file  named a.out, you can execute this by the command `./a.out`.
If you couldn't run or  your code check for the modes on file with `ls -la` command and if you can't find the letter -x in your files mode then use the command `chmod +x filename` .Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you all, Opened the Terminal in the same directory as the .out file, just typed in "./thefile.out" and it executed!